# Can you put content from your site on Facebook, or will that cause duplicate content?

Tags: facebook, duplicate-content, website-promotion

I have a question about duplicate content. Is it okay to take a paragraph or two directly from your website and put it on Facebook page as a post say, about your products or services, or even your about us page?

Does this harm your website ranking, have no impact or is it not worth doing because it may be problematic but there is no clear consensus?  A coworker and I have been discussing this where I admit to being more concerned about it than they are.

Comment: If it's just a paragraph or two, would it be that difficult to just re-write it to fit your Facebook audience anyway?

Comment: Good point by Andrew Lott. Aside from the issue of duplicate content for search engines, is duplicate content for users - it's not going to be engaging to Facebook users if they see the same exact thing on your site, and vice versa. Try to tailor each to the site they're on. Also, if the Facebook page isn't public, it's a mute point too.

Answer (score 1):

Copying content from one place to another with permission and proper attribution is called "Content Syndication".  Content syndication is fine, you just have to hide the content from Googlebot or tell Google where the content came from with a link to the original source.

Your Facebook page would link to your site.  That is proper syndicated content attribution.   So syndicating a couple paragraphs there wouldn't cause any problems.

Google also doesn't penalize for duplicate content unless it is a significant portion of a site.  Generally Google just ignores duplicate content in the place that it thinks is copy and only sends traffic to the original.  If there is plenty of other content on the Facebook page, a couple paragraphs that are not indexed is not going to cause any significant SEO issues.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same content from your page to post on Facebook page. Don't take risk. Though a paragraph or two, Google count it as content spam if it is present in other sites. Better use some other words to describe your post. I don't think that its a very difficult job to post a few fresh words on Facebook.